# Link list bind data to data grid

Tags: c#, xml

this is the code I tried my self. link list data should display on datagridview. but I am getting an error of from the 2 link of the code please try to fix this
Maxtemp and Max temp  coming weather class

```
 city = txttext.Text;
            string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?={0}&days=1 ", city);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uri);

      List<weather> we = new List<weather>();
        we.Add(new weather()  {  Maxtemp = (string)doc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault()});
        we.Add(new weather()  {  Mixtemp = (string)doc.Descendants("mixtemp_c").FirstOrDefault()});

         dataGridView1.DataSource = we;
```

this the weather class file i added  now i hope it is east to fix the problem
thanks

```
class weather
    {
        private string date;
        private string maxtemp;
        private string mintemp;
        private string maxwindmph;
        private string maxwindkph;
        private string humidity;

    public weather(string maxtemp, string mintemp, string maxwindmph, string maxwindkph, string humidity)
    {

        this.maxtemp = maxtemp;
        this.mintemp = mintemp;
        this.maxwindmph = maxwindmph;
        this.maxwindkph = maxwindkph;
        this.humidity = humidity;


    }

  public string Maxtemp
    {
        get { return maxtemp; }
        set { maxtemp = value; }
    }
    public string Mintemp
    {
        get { return mintemp; }
        set { mintemp = value; }
    }
    public string Maxwindmph
    {
        get { return maxwindmph; }
        set { maxwindmph = value; }
    }


    public string Humidity
    {
        get { return humidity; }
        set { humidity = value; }
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you specify the exact error message and on which line that error occurs.

Comment: we.Add(new weather()  {  Maxtemp = (string)doc.Descendants("maxtemp_c").FirstOrDefault()}); this line error display

Comment: You need to update your *question* to include that information *and the exact error text*.

Comment: We need "weather" class definition. We need to understand what is "doc" variable about. We need to known your error message and error type (compilation error, run-time error etc.)